# How to use jackson mixin on Jersey REST services method parameters

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I had Jackson deserializing problem of one of my java class which is come from third party API that doesn't have default constructors.To overcome that issue i used [JacksonMixIn](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) and it worked fine.But the problem was that i have a REST endpoint implemented on Jersey API which is accepted one of above mentioned classes as a method parameter from client side to server side.So when deserializing it throws me following error.

```
No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class net.rcarz.jiraclient.Priority]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@558e8ae; line: 1, column: 454]...
```

**Affected classes**

```
public class TestCaseVO{
   private Priority priority;
   private User reporter;
}

public class Priority {
   protected Priority(RestClient restclient, JSONObject json) {
    super(restclient);

    if (json != null)
        deserialise(json);
}
}
```

**This is the object used to communicate client to server**

```
public class myDataObject{
      private String userName;
      private List<TestCaseVO> testCases;
      //Getter and setters
    }
```

**Jersey Endpoint**

```
    @POST
    @Path("/bug")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public TestCaseVO attachBugForTestCase(myDataObject myDataObject){

    // when deserializing to MyDataObject it thorows above error
    //Handle logic
    }
```

**Client side code snippet**

```
var myDataObject= {
    "testCases": [$scope.bug.TestCaseVO],
    "userName":userName}

 angularJsMyService.Bug.attachBug({},myDataObject)
                                .$promise.then(function(data){
    ...
  }
```

My question is that how can i use Jackson mixin on REST methods parameters prior to Jackson deserializing them.Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you probably didn’t integrate Jackson with Jersey in the right way. Check out [Jersey’s doc on Jackson](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson). In your project, there should be a class implementing `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>`. The `ObjectMapper` instance returned by `getContext(Class<?> type)` in this class is used by Jersey’s REST endpoints. You may to configure that `ObjectMapper` with your Mix-in.